# Hitman Blood Money freezes

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, hitman-blood-money

I'm playing Hitman Blood Money on Windows 7 6-4bit. When starting the mission entitled "The murder of the crows" it crashes.

Does anyone know about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the obvious: check that you have the last patch (seems 1.2) installed and that the your video graphics card drivers are updated.

Then you can try some tricks to see if you can avoid that crash:

- Try to play that mission in window-mode
- Try to disable DirectX hardware sound acceleration: run dxdiag -> Tab Sound -> set **Hardware Sound Acceleration Level** to **Basic acceleration** or **No acceleration**

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that your game is crashing because of the large number of moving objects on the screen.

The Murder of Crows level is completely filled with NPCs that are always constantly moving, and your graphics card may be overwhelmed. Before you play the mission, tone down your graphics settings.